# Debian VM with Parallels space zero

Tags: linux, debian

I'm a new user of Linux and installed a Debian 8 VM with Parallels in a MacBook Pro. The MacBook Pro has 256 GB space and I have given the Debian 128 GB space (half). I installed only a few apps which should not take a lot of space. I started to get the message that the desk space is very little and needs to delete some apps soon.

I deleted few apps (e.g Skype) but I don't have much there except IntelliJ and Slack. At this point, it encountered a login loop of the machine where I put the correct password and it loops me back on the same screen. I speculated this due to the space reason. I entered the shell `(CNTR+ALT+FN+F3)` and I can get the visual mode with `startx` both as user and the root.

Now, it says I have no space left AT ALL.

[image]

I did some investigation and find the data from the terminal,

[image]

[image]

As it can be seen, the FileSystem /dev/sda1 is almost full and I wonder why. What should I do at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be your linked drives to your OSX. The /media/ mounts. Can you try to unmount those to see if that clears up space for you?

You can also run `cd / && du -sh *` and then `cd` into the largest of the directories and run `du -sh *` again. Keep going down the list of the largest directories.

To unmount a drive use `umount /media/XXXX` where XXXX is the name of the directory.

Comment: I'm a new user in Linux. Would you please update the answer to write how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean using the cd to drill down?

Comment: See my edits to commands

Comment: @Artin -- did this help?

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded 100 GB Blockchain data with geth that I was not aware off. Now considering to get larger SSD as the solution